# how to redirect pages to newdomain pages?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects

hi guys I have a domain named old.com and it has some pages , how can I redirect all those pages to their new address using htaccess? currently only old.com redirects to new.com but old.com/posts/ won't redirect to new.com/posts/ . Can anybody give me a htaccess code that passes the pagerank to new.com and redirects all pages to their new address ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will redirect all pages from old domain to new domain :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Please specify actual domain name in above code.